# How do i fix this error? required double, double; found double;

Tags: java, object

```
public class Account{
```

//instance variables

```
private double balance;
private double interestRate;
```

//constructors

```
public void Account(double initialBalance) {
     if (balance < 0) {
     balance = initialBalance;
     }
}

public void Account() {
     balance = 0.0;
}
```

//instance methods

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
     double backup = balance;
     balance = balance - amount;
     if (balance < 0) {
          System.out.println("error");
          balance = backup;
     }
}
```

//method used to withdraw

```
public void deposit(double amount) {
      balance = balance + amount;
      if (balance >= 10000){
           System.out.println("You are now rich");
      }
}

public double getBalance() {
     return balance;
}

public double setInterest(double rate){
     interestRate = rate;
}

public double computeInterest (int n) {
     double computeInterest = Math.pow(interestRate + balance * n);
     return computeInterest;
```

}

//this method contains the error and says it requires two doubles but can only //find one

```
public void close() {
     balance = 0.0;
}
```

//method used to close the balance

```
}
```

Comment: constructors don't need `void` before their name

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: While we're on about errors, `setInterest` says it returns a double but does not return anything.

Answer (score 2):

You're giving only one parameter to `Math.pow()` in your `computeInterest()` method. It takes two doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
double computeInterest = Math.pow(interestRate + balance * n);
```

With the following line

```
double computeInterest = Math.pow(interestRate + balance , n);
```

`Math.pow(a,b)` takes two parameters. The first parameter is the base and the second parameter is the exponent and it return `a^b`. So you are getting the error as you pass only one parameter

Comment: You should elaborate on what the difference is.

Comment: I am assuming `n` is the exponent and `interestRate + balance` is the base